# Integrate a general menu in my asp.net mvc solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

For my learning, I'm building a document management solution with ASP.NET MVC3. Below are pages I manage:

> - a search/result page (list of items)
> - a favorite page (list of items)
> - an edit page
> - a create page

I also have a Site.Master page where I show a treeview menu on the left side of the screen. So wherever the user is located in the website, the treeview menu is showing his location by underlining his location in the menu.

For building the treeview menu, I use the code below (cleaned for easy reading):

```
        <ul id="treemenu1" class="treeview">                                    
                <li>Documents
                    <ul>  
                        <%= Html.TreeviewMenu(TreeMenu.Create("Search", "Search", "Affaires", null))%>
                        <%= Html.TreeviewMenu(TreeMenu.Create("Favorite", "Favorite", "Affaires", null))%>
                        <%= Html.TreeviewMenu(TreeMenu.Create("New", "Create", "Affaires", null))%>
                   </ul>  
                </li>
        </ul>
```

The problem is that I need to underline the active item in my menu. So if user is displaying the search page, my search menu entry must be underlined. How can I proceed? I was thinking about the integration of this information in the strongly typed viewmodel passed to each viewpage but it failed because each page is using a different viewmodel. I prefer not using a session variable because it is not a clean solution.

Any ideas?

**A solution with a session variable:** I save the "current menu item" in a session variable (from my controller). So, whenever the Site.Master page is reloaded, it recreate every treeview menu item. For each one, it checks if the item is equal to the session variable. If yes, the class "selected" is added to the item (css highlighted with blue).

I don't really like using session variables. Maybe there are more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string text,
    string action, 
    string controller
)
{
    var li = new TagBuilder("li");
    var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
    var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        li.AddCssClass("active");
    }
    li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
}
```

and then:

```
<ul>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("Search", "Search", "Affaires") %>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("Favorite", "Favorite", "Affaires") %>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("New", "Create", "Affaires") %>
</ul>
```

which could yield the following if you navigate to `/Affaires/Favorite`:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/Affaires/Search">Search</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/Affaires/Favorite">Favorite</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Affaires/Create">New</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yup, probably the most logical thing to do. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Darin: your solution is the most logical effectively. That was that solution that I used at the very beginning. Until I used a form in my page for managing checked items in the resulting table of my search page. If the form is submitted and threated in my controller (posting my form to the action called ManageCheckedItems) and next we return to the same view page. Then the Site.Master page is reloaded and the html helper (as yours) is executed. The **problem here** is that the routeData.GetRequiredString("action") here is equal to ManageCheckedItems and not Search!

Comment: That was my big problem with this solution. So to summarize: If I use a form with a post action different from the initial action page I have a problem when going back to reload my page. I don't know if I'm clear.

Comment: @Bronzato, you are perfectly clear. I understand the problem. It's an issue with persisting the calling action which is lost during the POST. One possible workaround would be to include the original action and controller as part of the POST request (maybe in a hidden fields with some predefined names). Then in the helper you could check the HTTP verb and if it is POST look at the POSTed data for those values and if you identify their presence use them for comparison instead of the once fetched from `RouteData`.

Comment: @Darin: it annoys me... I fear that this initially good solution turns into a complicated solution... Maybe another "cleaner" solution is possible?

Comment: @Bronzato, is posting the form with AJAX an alternative to you?

Comment: @Darin, yes it can be an alternative but posting a form with ajax is the same problem isn't?

Comment: @Bronzato, no because you will update only portions of the DOM when you submit the form and the portion that contains the menu could stay the same.

Comment: @Darin: I see what you mean. Unfortunately my view is composed of 3 partial views and after posting my form I really need to update (at least) 2 of the 3 partial views. As far as I know we can only update one target after an ajax post, right? This problem drives me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one easy and effective solution: let each page signal whether it's the active page and set a css class with jQuery.

Assuming your rendered html looks like:

```
<ul id="treemenu1" class="treeview">                                    
    <li>Documents
        <ul>
            <li class="search"></li>
            <li class="favorite"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

At the bottom of each page, do something like (this would sit on the search view):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Set active nav
        $('#treemenu1 li.search').addClass('selected');
    });
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE based on new info**

A little cleaner than a session vraiable could be to use the `ViewBag` property from the controller.

```
public ActionResult Search(/*whatever*/)
{
    // do things

    // set the selevted view
    ViewBag.SelectedMenuItem = "search";

    return View();
}
```

Then in your master page you can check against `<%: ViewBag.SelectedMenuItem %>`

Note that `SelectedMenuItem` is a random name. [The `ViewBag` property is of type `dynamic`](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx) so you can use any property name you like.

Comment: it may be a solution but I have the same viewpage used for multiple purpose (search, favorite, ...) so in this situation i have a problem. Otherwise your solution works. I'll think about it. Maybe there are other alternatives? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato - what do you mean exactly by "same viewpage for multiple purposes"?

Comment: I mean that I have a page named Search.aspx used for both the search and the Favorite menu option. I added more info in my question (see above).